# unable to view plunker results

Tags: plunker

Suddenly, some of my plunkers are giving the following error when I try to run since last 4 days.

```
{
  "statusCode": 404,
  "error": "Not Found"
}
```

Please refer one of my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/wWJx3zU3Sm1cN9ZCtvoh?p=preview, earlier it is used to run fine but now when I try to run this plunker it is giving me the above error.  What is the resolution for this?

Comment: I will need to investigate this. This is pretty unusual.

Comment: I get this when I scan the barcode with my phone and try to view it on my mobile browser: http://run.plnkr.co/ABYsPTajoarDm2MM/